# Form validation with Javascript - Need red "*"

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a simple formular like this example:

Firstname: **INPUTFIELD**
Lastname: **INPUTFIELD**

SUBMITBUTTON

This form should validate with javascript if i click the submitbutton.
If the validation fails (for example i forgott to enter a firstname) i want a red "*" after "Firstname" and befor the inputfield, like this:

Firstname: * **INPUTFIELD**
Lastname: **INPUTFIELD**

SUBMITBUTTON

Which is the clearest way to solve this in javascript? 
My actually solution is this:

```
<p id="pFirstname">Firstname: &#160; <input type="input" name="firstname" id="firstnameid"></p> 

document.getElementById("pFirstname").innerHTML  = "Firstname* : &#160; <input type=\"input\" name=\"firstname\" id=\"firstnameid\">";</code>
```

But here i have the problem, that the "*" is not red. And i want to handle this by CSS. But here i only have the whole "Firstname: INPUTFIELD" paragraph....My problem is the auto-line-break of the p element...

Comment: You might want to put a span in the innerHTML to style the * red. If you need help on the validation, too, you need to look into event listeners (the onclick one, probably).

Comment: Sure! The answers below have the code, so you should mark one if you think it helped too.

Answer (score 0):

Put a span in HTML like this

```
Firstname:<span id="firstNameValid" style="color:red;"></span> <input type="input" name="firstname" id="firstnameid">
```

and in validation function of javascript, if validation fails,

```
var validChar = isValidated ? '' : '*';//If validated, clear * and if not display *
try{
    document.getElementById("firstNameValid").innerHTML = validChar;
}catch(e){
    document.getElementById("firstNameValid").innerText = validChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use CSS + DOM to implement this.

1) Create the asterisk marker at page load, but leave it invisible by wrapping it inside a `span` tag using `display:none;` - like this:

```
<p id="pFirstname">
    Firstname:
    <span id='pFirstnameValMark' style='display:none;color:red;'> &#160;</span>
    <input type="input" name="firstname" id="firstnameid">
</p>
```

2) If validation fails - display it:

```
pFirstnameValMark.style.display='inline';
```

3) You may hide it again (say, if the user starts editing the field):

```
pFirstnameValMark.style.display='none';
```

I used inline style to demonstrate mechanics, but you can improve the solution by incorporating the CSS definition into classes.

And leave the `InnerHTML` property alone. You're manipulating visibility, not content. ;)

Answer (score 0):

place span tags around your asterisk in your innerHTML output and stylize that with css:

JS:

```
document.getElementById("pFirstname").innerHTML  = "Firstname<span style=\"color:#900;\"> * <\\span> : &#160; <input type=\"input\" name=\"firstname\" id=\"firstnameid\">";
```

I'm not sure if you need to escape the Less Than and Greater Than tags, but if you do it would simply be `&lt;` and `&gt;`